# Node.js remote debug doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, remote-debugging, javascript-debugger

When I start my node application as `node --debug . -c=config-name` option there no any message about listening any port.

Also if I run `netstat -tlnp` I can't see any application listening port 5858.

By this reason I can't use any debugger such as node-inspector or intellij Idea node plugin.

Any ideas how I can resolve it?

Comment: Can you cut and paste what you see in your terminal? Also, there is no `-c` flag for the node interpreter.

Comment: probably your programm exited already? use --debug-brk to stop execution first

Comment: don't use the -- in front of debug `node debug . -c=config-name` See the example here http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_debugger

Comment: --debug-brk doesn't change anything(except program not stat in this case). So I run it for example this way:
`vagrant@precise64:~$ node chat.js --debug-brk`
But there no any output.
For netstat: `vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo netstat -tlnp|grep 5858
` and there also no output.

Somewhy debug works now on my host machine(not worked when I asked question). But it doesn't work inside vagrant environment.
And I know what `node debug .` do, but it's not what I need.

Comment: `node chat.js --debug-brk` will not work because the debug statements are being passed to your script, not to node. It needs to come first like `node --debug-brk chat.js`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ohh I got it! `--debug` should be entered BEFORE path to executable.

For example `vagrant@precise64:~$ node chat.js --debug` doesn't work.

But in this case it works:

`vagrant@precise64:~$ node --debug chat.js`

```
debugger listening on port 5858`
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone! And sorry about losing your time.